# Uber API Limit of 5 APPS?

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to make uber deeplinks for my clients but says I am limited to making 5 APPS, how do I make more than 5? I currently have over 200 locations. Should I make 1 app for all 200 locations using the same client id for all?

Comment: nobody knows how to make more than 5 deep links per login?

Comment: There is not a limit of 5 deeplinks. You can create as many deeplinks as you want using the tool here: https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink

Or look at the deeplink documentation and create them yourself.